# STM32 cant get DMA on PWM

Tags: pwm, stm32, dma, ws2812b

I wish to drive a set of NEOPIXELS (ws2812b) using the STM32F4 discovery board, so far i managed to get a 800 kHz PWM signal using the CubeMX.
[image]

And

[image]
And the following code:

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);

/* USER CODE END 2 */
```

But when i add these lines of code

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Init */
uint16_t pData[25] = {8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0};

/* USER CODE END Init */
```

...

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

//HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
HAL_TIM_PWM_Start_DMA(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1, (uint32_t *)pData, 25);

/* USER CODE END 2 */
```

My PWM signal just disappears, what do i need to do to control the PWM with DMA?

**edit:**
It is posting the DMA sequence, but the DMA needs to be changed to circular to see it on a scope

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86578/discussion-on-question-by-bart-admiraal-stm32-cant-get-dma-on-pwm).

Answer (score 2):

The code was correctly transmitting the DMA sequence, but the DMA needed to be changed to circular or repeating mode to see it on a scope.  When it was just running in linear or one-shot mode, I didn't have a chance to see the output the single time it was produced.

Comment: Is this the solution to your issue, or just an additional clarification?